# How to reset apache server in fedora

Tags: apache-http-server, fedora

I had messed up with Apache server's config because of which the server was not working. It showed this:

[image: output]

I installed Apache using `sudo dnf install httpd php`. I deleted `/etc/httpd`. and re-installed Apache. The error still persists. How can I reset Apache?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted the fedora paritition. Re-installed Fedora, apache and php. It works now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/838261)

Comment: I am the author of the question. After no reply, I was forced to do the above. @Mureinik. I have purposely not marked my answer correct because many people might not be able to start from scratch. I am waiting for that answer